# Dynamically Setting and Getting an Object

Tags: angularjs, oop, dynamic

How do I dynamically specify a value in my AdminActivtyService object? I have a setEmbeddedConfigObj to change numActivities to false or true. However, if I want to set or get socialMediaSelections, how would I specify to set socialMediaSelections and NOT numActivities.

I also do not want excessive different set and get functions for each value in my embedConfigObj.

Thus, is there a way to have something like  "this.embeddedConfigObj.obj = obj". This would allow only the value that the function parameters passed in to be set or get.

```
 var AdminActivityService = {
        "embeddedConfigObj" : {

            "numActivities" : false,
            "socialMediaSelections": false
            // etc.
        }
 };


 AdminActivityService.setEmbeddedConfigObj = function(obj) {

     this.embeddedConfigObj.numActivities = obj;
 };

 AdminActivityService.getEmbeddedConfigObj = function() {

     return this.embeddedConfigObj.numActivities;
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the key name as well as the value and have one getter/setter:

```
AdminActivityService.getEmbeddedConfigObj = function(key) {
    if (this.embeddedConfigObj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        return this.embeddedConfigObj[key];
    else
        return null;
}

AdminActivityService.setEmbeddedConfigObj = function(key, val) {
    if (this.embeddedConfigObj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        this.embeddedConfigObj[key] = val;
}
```

Then simply call it: `AdminActivityService.getEmbeddedConfigObj("numActivities")` will return the value for `numActivities` and `AdminActivityService.setEmbeddedConfigObj("numActivities", true)` would set `numActivities` to `true`